# Selenium .click() for trulia.com search button not clicking

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to scrape some data off of trulia.com. The code I have thus far finds the element to click but never actually click it. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

def get_trulia_estimate(address):
    driver.get('https://www.trulia.com/')
    print(address)
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('homepageSearchBoxTextInput')
    element.click()
    element.send_keys(address)
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-auto-test-id='searchButton']")
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(3) 

get_trulia_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, CA 92651')


driver.quit()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to implement waits so selenium can make sure the element is ready to be clicked before sending clicks and keys.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

def get_trulia_estimate(address):
    driver.get('https://www.trulia.com/')
    print(address)
    element = (By.ID, 'homepageSearchBoxTextInput')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(element)).send_keys(address)

    search_button = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-auto-test-id='searchButton']")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(search_button)).click()

    time.sleep(3) 

get_trulia_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, CA 92651')


driver.quit()
```

Also, it is better to use selenium's implicit_wait() function instead of time.sleep(). Due to OS process scheduling time.sleep() can either run for less or more time than you tell it too which can potentially mess with seleniums webdriver.

Comment: TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebElement

Comment: Sorry about that, try using By. For example element = (By.ID, "homepageSearchBoxTextInput")

Comment: Now I have this error: TypeError: find_element_by_id() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Please test answer before posting

Comment: Your updated code runs but its the same problem as before. It finds the element but does not click it.

Comment: This could happen for a number of reasons including older versions, unsupported version on particular operating systems, even too many runs. I've been having problems with too many requests to certain sites which then block me from using the button for 24 hours.

Comment: Does your code work? If so, what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: Mine works. Selenium - 3.13.0 geckodriver - 0.17.0 firefox - 52.9.0 on raspberry pi. I have copied and pasted code like this onto my windows pc and it worked there too but I can't test that until I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `WebdriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`.

```
    def get_trulia_estimate(address):
    driver.get('https://www.trulia.com/')
    print(address)
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('homepageSearchBoxTextInput')
    element.click()
    element.send_keys(address)
    WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[data-auto-test-id='searchButton'] i.iconSearch"))).click()


get_trulia_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, CA 92651')
```

Comment: This does not work, it finds the element but does not click it

Comment: @Wolfy : Try now and let me know.

Comment: Same problem :/ finds the element but does not click

Comment: That is really strange what OS are you using?

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: windows 10 , selenium 3.14 , browser chrome and firefox,python 3.6

Comment: I have the same setup

Comment: but it just gets hung up on the first page and does click to the address specified

Comment: @Wolfy : This is really strange every time i ran my code and it is clicking on the search button

Comment: What version is your chromedriver.exe?

Comment: Chromedriver 74 & chromebrowser 74

Comment: I am using chromedriver 75 and chromebrowser 75 and with your code I am getting this error message: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I am not sure about version 75 not tested yet.can you try on Firefox browser with gecko driver and let me know.for me that worked as well

Comment: I tried with Firefox but unfortunately we have corporate proxies that prevent using firefox.

Comment: Try using actions object for this. May be the screen resolution is causing the problem. Build the actions object by moving the mouse pointer to the element then click it. If this does not work use javascript to click
driver.execute_script('$("<JQuery path of the element>").click()')